# Do I need multiple test adjustments when do the permutation test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

I have bulit the model to predict some property of genes (classification problem, 1/0) and I want to test whether a certain gene set has significantly more genes predicted to be class 1 in a certain sample. I done a permutation test. For example, a sample has 100 genes, and the gene set to be tested has 10 genes, among which 8 genes are predicted to be class 1. I randomly selected 10 genes from the 100 genes in the sample and calculated the proportion of these 10 random gene that predicted to be 1, this process was repeated 1000 times to obtain 1000 proportions, and then the proportion greater than 0.8 among the 1000 values is calculated, which is the P value. If I have 3000 samples, each with 50 different gene sets, that is, a total of 3000 * 50 permutation tests, do I need to perform multiple hypothesis testing correction?